# Problema al listar datos desde una DB con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo estas tablas

trabajo

```
id(int) | titulo(varchar) | miembros(varchar)
----------------------------------------------
1       | Primera nota    | 1,2
```

usuario

```
id(int) | nombre(varchar)
--------------------------
1       | Pedro
2       | Lucas
```

formulario.php

```
<?php

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$notas = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM trabajo INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.id = trabajo.miembros");
while($row = $notas->fetch()){

?>
<p>
&rarr; <?=$row['titulo'];?> - Miembros: <?=$row['nombre'];?>,

<!--
Respuesta:  Primera nota -  Miembros: Pedro
-->

</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Lo que intento hacer es listar los trabajos con sus miembros, pero como resultado solo obtengo el primer `id`, un solo nombre y no sé como solucionarlo.

Comment: tu consulta está mal hecha para empezar.

Comment: gracias, ahora me dejas pensando en como resolver la consulta

Comment: Es cosa de mirar... en la consulta estás uniendo la tabla trabajo -> `usuario.id = trabajo.miembros` cuando en la tabla trabajo que muestras no hay una columna miembros.

Comment: Perdón, ya lo arregle. Pero sigue igual, solo me trar el nombre de un miembro

Comment: Corrige la publicacion y haz una correcta identacion a ver que tienes ahora

Comment: Ya esta corregida

Comment: El problema son tus tablas y tu consulta. Están mal construidas. Para empezar, el campo miembros, es un varchar y con quien lo comparas es un int. Siguiendo esa lógica, tus miembros serían algo como: `"1, 2"` si comparo eso con **1** , no son iguales por lo tanto no traerá nada.

Comment: Comprendo, pero si cambio la tabla a `int` no me va a dejar agregar valores con coma, por ende, voy a tener que pasar esos string a enteros.

Comment: @gaidyjg Otra cosa que veo es me trae uno de los miembros, esta mal, pero no se como logra comprar un string con un entero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fijate de hacer dos consultas en vez de una. Probalo.

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'pruebas', 3306);

$trabajo = "SELECT * FROM trabajo";
$row = $conn->query($trabajo);

while ($fila = $trabajos->fetch_array()) {

    $miembros = explode(',',$fila[2]);
    echo $fila[1].' Miembros: ';

    for($i=0; $i < count($miembros); $i++){
       $usuario = $conn->query("SELECT * from usuario where id = '" . $miembros[$i] . "' ");

       $rows = $usuario->fetch_row();
       echo  (count($miembros)-$i)==1? $rows[1]:$rows[1].', ';
   }

echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Gracias Antonia. Lo pruebo y te digo.

Answer (score 0):

Para vincular las dos tablas en MySql en este caso puedes utilizar la función `FIND_IN_SET(valor-buscado, lista-valores)`. `FIND_IN_SET` se utiliza para buscar un valor en una lista de valores separados por coma; si encuentra el valor retorna la posición del mismo en la lista, en caso contrario retornará 0:

```
SELECT *
FROM trabajo t
INNER JOIN usuario u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id, t.miembros);
```

**Salida** (con los datos de ejmplo de la pregunta):

| id | titulo | miembros | id | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Primera nota | 1,2 | 1 | Pedro |
| 1 | Primera nota | 1,2 | 2 | Lucas |

Si quires obtener una sola fila por trabajo, puedes utilizar esta query (agrupando por título y concatenando los nombres de los usuarios):

```
SELECT titulo, group_concat(nombre SEPARATOR ', ') AS usuarios
FROM trabajo t
INNER JOIN usuario u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id, t.miembros)
GROUP BY titulo;
```

**Salida** (con los datos de ejmplo de la pregunta):

| titulo | usuarios |
| --- | --- |
| Primera nota | Pedro, Lucas |

No es aconsejable guardar un lista de IDs en una columna como llaves foraneas, como se trata de una relación de muchos a muchos, deberías utilizar una tercer tabla para vincular que tenga como columnas id_trabajo, id_usuario, lo cual te facilitará mucho las queries. Lee acerca de normalización en bases de datos.